# Want to have view as Image Attached using UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]Hi

In my app, i have a requirement to make this grid view..type....i want to do it by UITableView...(Although done via scroll view)

My Query is , by using custom cell, in 1 row, there will be 1 custom cell with 4 image view in it...

so now on image tapping how will i know which image inside cell is tapped????

or second option i thought..as each image as custom cell..but dont know how to proceed furthur....as how can we get 2 adjacent cell in 1 row????

Also wanna know which method is better...as this grid view will be containing 50 images around....and on tapping bigger view opens with scrolling...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a custom UIButton inside the UIView and set a background image and a selector.

Something like this :

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[buttonHolder addSubview:button]; //buttonHolder will be one of the UIView in your cell
```

Answer (score 0):

i have create image gallery view using scroll view [gallery view](http://geekios.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/how-to-make-image-gallery-view-in-iphone/)

if you want to make in table view you have to create custom cell with 4 image view and a single button each image attached with image tag when a button pressed it get the tag number and you can find which of image button is clicked.